# java script function not invoking from html button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, jsp, internet-explorer

I am calling a js function in my spring boot - jsp war project, but the function is not getting invoked on the button click in IE browser.

```
<input type="button" id="btnEditUsrUpdate" value="Save" class="button" style="display: none;" onclick="updateUsers();">
```

But it is work if i am using jquery.

```
$('#btnEditUsrUpdate').click(function() {});
```

Note: Both cases are working in other browsers.

code:`

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    checkUserRole();
    if(('${makerCheckerFlag}'=='N')&& ('${groupSerialNumber}'!=1)){
        document.getElementById("divUsrEditType").style.display = 'none';
    }
         var userRight=validateUserRight('${userAccessRights}',"2");
            if(userRight==true){
        document.getElementById("btnEditUsrUpdate").style.display="";
        document.getElementById("btnEditUsrClear").style.display="";
        }
    var insCode=document.getElementById('hdnInstitutionCode').value;
    if(insCode==0){
        document.getElementById("formUsrEditProfile").disabled = "";
        document.getElementById("formUsrEditGroup").disabled = "";
        document.getElementById("divUsrEditRole").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("spanUsrEditProfile").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("divUsrEditType").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("ddlEditUsrUserGroup").disabled = "disabled";
        document.getElementById("ddlEditUsrUserProfile").disabled = "disabled";
    }else{
        
        document.getElementById("formUsrEditProfile").disabled = "true";
        document.getElementById("formUsrEditGroup").disabled = "true";
    }
    $("form").bind("keyup", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 13) {
            liveValidation();
        } else{
            updateUsers();
        }
        return false;
    });
    
    var userRole=document.getElementById("ddlEditUsrUserRole").value;
    
    if(userRole=='Y'||userRole=='A'||userRole=='D'){
        document.getElementById("divUsrEditType").style.display='none';
    }else{
        document.getElementById("divUsrEditType").style.display='table-row';
    }
    
});`
```

Comment: `style="display: none;" ` how would you click? Can you share more code? Click edit and then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: i am unhiding this in $(document).ready(function() based on some conditions.  Like this   document.getElementById("btnEditUsrUpdate").style.display="";

Comment: Please show us that

Comment: Is there any error in console when it doesn't work in IE? How do you define the `updateUsers` function? I can't reproduce the issue using the code you provide, please provide related code which can **reproduce the issue**.